# Invióke Spring Service

Tags: spring, rest

I have offered a method to change password with @RequestBody Parameter netPassword and oldPassword. Currently I don't know how to invoke the method ("old,new" not working).
I always get the following exception:

> Required request body content is missing

It would be great if someone could give me a hint solving this problem

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changepassword", method = { RequestMethod.PUT }, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody User changePassword(final @RequestBody String newPassword, final @RequestBody String oldPassword)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one argument can be annotated with RequestBody. Create a class like

```
public class ChangePasswordCommand {
    private String oldPassword;
    private String newPassword;

    // getters and setters omitted, but necessary
}
```

then use

```
@ResponseBody 
public User changePassword(@RequestBody ChangePasswordCommand command)
```

And send the command as JSON:

```
{"oldPassword" : "old", "newPassword": "new"}
```